# Mysql if value equal condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Codeigniter code:

```
if(Property.Property_for == 1)
$this->db->join('Property_sell','Property_sell.Property_id = Property.ID','left');
else
$this->db->join('Property_rent','Property_rent.Property_id = Property.ID','left');
```

How can I make query like given example?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to toggle the join table and column.

```
$table = 'rent';
if(Property.Property_for == 1) {
    $table = 'sell';
}
$tableColumn = sprintf('Property_%s', $table);
$this->db->join($tableColumn, $tableColumn . '.Property_id = Property.ID','left');
```

If this is not what you are trying achieve, please expand your question.